# Spring Social LinkedIn - how to conditionally redirect or pass parameters?

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-linkedin

We're using Spring Social LinkedIn in a single page javascript app to authenticate a user.  We're able to successfully authenticate against LinkedIn, but we're having trouble getting that to integrate with our javascript app.  It actually breaks down into two issues:

Issue 1:
We're using one API key for a set or related apps - and we use a single sign-in process.  We need a way to identifiy which app the user came from and to send them back to the right app after logging in.  The problem we're having is LinkedIn only allows one redirect URL and I don't believe it can carry any parameters (that would probably be the solution if it's possible to carry a parameter like the identifier of the app they're in).  Do you know of a way to conditionally redirect the person after login?

Issue 2:
When the user is authenticated, we store the user info in our database, but after that we need the log the user into our app and provide the user with a token.  Is there a way after the LinkedIn authentication completes to trigger another call to the server to request the token?